# How to sort fetch request by related properties?

Tags: sorting, core-data, relationship, nssortdescriptor

I have two CoreData entities with one-to-many relation - `Contact` (main) and `PhoneNumber` (related)

Contact can has several phone numbers, and I need to sort `Contacts` by `PhoneNumbers` property, and I want to sort it by existing of `true` values in `registered` property, eg:

```
Contact1
  prop1 = "value1"
  prop2 = "value2"
  PhoneNumbers = [
    {prop1 = "value1", prop2 = "value2", registered = false},
    {prop1 = "value1", prop2 = "value2", registered = false}
  ]

Contact2
  prop1 = "value1"
  prop2 = "value2"
  PhoneNumbers = [
    {prop1 = "value1", prop2 = "value2", registered = false},
    {prop1 = "value1", prop2 = "value2", registered = false},
    {prop1 = "value1", prop2 = "value2", registered = true}
  ]

Contact3
  prop1 = "value1"
  prop2 = "value2"
  PhoneNumbers = [
    {prop1 = "value1", prop2 = "value2", registered = false},
    {prop1 = "value1", prop2 = "value2", registered = false}
  ]
```

`Contact2` has `PhoneNumber` with `registered = true`, and I want move it to fetching result's top

My sort descriptor:

```
[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"phoneNumbers" ascending:YES selector:@selector(registeredCompare:)];
```

When I specifies `phoneNumbers` key (as relationship in data model), I receives error `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'to-many key not allowed here'`

When I changes key to another, error changes to `unsupported NSSortDescriptor selector: registeredCompare:` even if argument type is correct

How can I sort data by related properties?

Comparators (`NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:ascending:comparator:`) are not supported by `NSFetchRequest`
Get all values to array and sort it is not a solution - too many contacts can freeze application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't sort by a to-many relationship.  There are potentially several PhoneNumbers for each Contact; to decide which Contact comes first, CoreData needs a single value for each Contact.

Your second error is because `registeredCompare` is not a recognised sort selector.  From the [Core Data Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/PersistentStoreFeatures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001075-CH23-SW1):

> The supported sort selectors for SQLite are compare: and caseInsensitiveCompare:, localizedCompare:, localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:, and localizedStandardCompare:.

One solution to your problem would be to add a boolean attribute to the `Contact` entity, say `hasRegisteredPhoneNumber` which you update to true or false when you add/change/remove related PhoneNumbers.  Then use that new attribute as a sort key.